# La cuenta atrás no se para

Tags: c#, unity3d

Necesito saber cómo debo hacer para que, al final de la cuenta atrás, el mensaje "se acabó el tiempo" sólo salga una vez. De momento se repite continuamente.

Aquí les dejo el código que tengo implementado para que puedan analizar, encontrar el problema o hacerme alguna sugerencia:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CuentaAtras : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tiempo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (tiempo > 0)
        {
          tiempo = tiempo - 1;
           Debug.Log(tiempo);
        }
        if (tiempo == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Se acabo el tiempo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No se entiende nada de esta pregunta. Que cuenta atras? cuando se ejecuta update? como funciona este codigo? Obviamente hay que dejar que se ejecute Update, pero quien lo ejecuta?

Comment: @gbianchi faltaba un tag haciendo referencia a Unity3D, pero podía deducirse por el `using UnityEngine`. La clase `MonoBehaviour` hace una llamada a `Update()` en cada fotograma, pero (tal y como pongo en mi respuesta) no se puede evitar esa llamada, sólo decidir si hacer algo o no en su interior. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Solucionó mi respuesta tu problema? Si es así te agradecería que la marcaras como correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En Unity no existe la posibilidad de evitar que se ejecuten las consiguientes llamadas a [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) aunque haya finalizado el contador, por lo que debes mantener una variable para saber si el contador está activo o bien un valor de éste para determinar que éste está inactivo.

Una solución podría ser con una variable que almacene el estado de "contador activo" y otra podría ser estableciendo un valor reservado para cuando el contador esté inactivo (por ejemplo, el valor -1).

## Variable de estado

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CuentaAtras : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tiempo;
    public bool habilitado;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        /* Marcamos el contador como habilitado */
        habilitado = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        /* Comprobamos si el contador está habilitado */
        if (habilitado == true) {
            if (tiempo > 0)
            {
              tiempo = tiempo - 1;
               Debug.Log(tiempo);
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Se acabo el tiempo");
                /* Marcamos el contador como deshabilitado */
                habilitado = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Valor especial para estado final

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CuentaAtras : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tiempo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        /* Comprobamos si el contador sigue activo */
        if (tiempo != -1) {
            if (tiempo > 0)
            {
               tiempo = tiempo - 1;
               Debug.Log(tiempo);
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Se acabo el tiempo");
                /* Marcamos el tiempo como finalizado */
                tiempo = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no puedes evitar que se llame el update basta con que en el segundo if hagas los siguiente:

```
if (tiempo == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Se acabo el tiempo");
            tiempo--;
        }
```

al decrementar la variable tiempo esta se hace -1, por lo tanto no volverá a entrar en el if y ya no se desplegará el mensaje